# Bash Command for Finding the size of all files with particular filetype in a directory in ubuntu

Tags: linux, bash, shell, file-type

I have a folder which contains several file types say .html,.php,.txt etc.. and it has sub folders also .Sub folders may contain all the file types mentioned above.

**Question1**:- I want to find size of all the files having the file type as '.html' which are there in both root directory and in sub- directories

**Question2**:- I want to find size of all the files having the file type as '.html' which are there only in root directory but not in sub folders.

I surfed through the internet but all i am able to get is commands like df -h, du -sh etc..

Are there any bash commands for the above questions? Any bash scripts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the find command for that.

```
#### Find the files recursively
find . -type f -iname "*.html"
#### Find the files on the r
find . -type f -maxdepth 1 -iname "*.iml"
```

Then, in order to get their size, you can use the -exec option like this:

```
find . -type f -iname "*.html" -exec ls -lha {} \;
```

And if you really only need the file size (I mean, without all the other stuff that ls prints):

```
find . -type f -iname "*.html" -exec stat -c "%s" {} \;
```

Explanation:

**iname** search of files without being case sensitive

**maxdepth** travels subdirectories recursively up to the specify level (1 means only the immediate folder)

**exec** executes an arbitrary command using the found paths, where "{}" represents the path of the file

**type** indicates the type of file (a directory is a file in Linux)